# Time profiler in instruments is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, instruments, xcode9.3

I recently update my Xcode to version 9.3, so is instruments. After that, time profiler won't work anymore, it usually works fine before.

I tried to run it via Xcode, and I tried to run it manually. Doesn't work.
The life cycle row stuck in initializing, and I got a bunch of warnings complain about **the data volume is too high for a recording mode of "immediate" and some data had to be dropped to move forward**.

Then I switch to delay mode, still got nothing. Then I create a simple new project, which should have "little data volume", still got nothing.

I checked help, I googled, seems like no one has encountered this before. Does anyone have any clue about this?

[image]

Comment: I found that Instruments only can work for an iOS 11.3 device.

Comment: I was hitting the same issue on 10.3.1 and 11.2.1 devices that had no problem with XCode 9.2
After upgrading one device to 11.3, time profiling started working again on it.
A bit annoying for a developer wanting to keep older iOS version around to test specific problems.
Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @HarrisonXi, yes works for me, thx. I wonder if they would release a new version to fix it. Because you cant update every device, for compatible debug reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was hitting the same issue for a week.

Since today, I change the Xcode Version back to `Xcode 9.2` - and the problem was resolved.

It seems like this is a bug of `Xcode 9.3`, I just filed an issue to Apple yesterday. No reply has been received.

Comment: XCode 9.4.1 with the device on iOS 11.4.1 works for me.

Comment: @RandyHill I come across the same issue when I am using Xcode 9.4 profile my project for an iOS 9.3.3 device, it seems like that Instrument of XCode 9.4 doesn't work for iOS 9.3.3, maybe this version of Xcode doesn't support iOS system version under iOS 11, that real sucks for developer profiling app to older version device.

Comment: @suxinde2009 Thanks for the update, I was profiling under iOS 11. I'll try Xcode 9.4.1 since it worked for Joseph.

Comment: @RandyHill - Update your Xcode to 9.4.1 and iPhone also to 11.4.1

Works for me.

Comment: XCode 10.1 with the device on iOS 12.1 works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had two versions of Xcode installed, and was experiencing this when using the Instruments associated with the oldest version of Xcode (9.4.1).

I solved the issue by using the Instruments associated with the newest version of Xcode I had installed (10.0)